# Why col-xs-3 sends next control with offset

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have 4 controls and wanted to display into col-12 grid system.

When I am using below code it is working fine on desktop but on mobile devices, this code is bringing 3rd control floating on right. Like in below examnple 'Plate State' comes below HBU5XD. I want it to below License State

Can someone please help me on it?

Thank you

Rushi

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
   
   <div class="row form-group" style="margin-top: 10px;" id="trans">

            <label class="control-label col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" for="number" id="label">License Plate:</label>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-9"> HBU5XD</div>

            <label class="control-label col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" for="state" id="label">Plate State:</label>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-9"> Nebraska </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a float clearing issue.  The easiest but least elegant solution would be to apply a `.clearfix` between the two content areas:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="row form-group" style="margin-top: 10px;" id="trans">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" for="number" id="label">License Plate:</label>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-9"> HBU5XD</div>
      
      <div class="clearfix visible-xs"></div>

      <label class="control-label col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" for="state" id="label">Plate State:</label>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-9"> Nebraska </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it is really not nice but it is working for me. I will see if other solution will not available then will accept this as an answer.  I am believing this is not new and a lot of people could have faced this. I am not sure why this was not fixed in the bootstrap way.

Comment: I've a feeling it has to do with the classes you're combining here like `.panel-body` and `.form-group`.  If you use just a standard Grid layout you get the expected results: https://www.bootply.com/1XUIfvK4Ya

Answer (score 0):

You need only set each control to col-xs-6 to ensure two of them fit side-by-side on each row.  This will apply to the mobile and any device that is larger.
You will also need to force the bottom-margin of the labels to 0 because that is what is causing them to float.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">

  <div class="row form-group" style="margin-top: 10px;" id="trans">

    <label class="control-label col-xs-6" for="number" id="label" style="margin-bottom:0px">License Plate:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-6"> HBU5XD</div>

    <label class="control-label col-xs-6" for="state" id="label" style="margin-bottom:0px">Plate State:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-6"> Nebraska </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Based on the OPs code it seems like on 'XS` devices they wanted two rows of content.  Your solution doesn't address that.

Comment: I don't want them side by side, I want it in next line.

Comment: Ah I see.  Correction made.